# Expression resolves to an unused i-value

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I am retrieving some data from database and appending them in an array. Then, (after retrieving completed), I reload data and put those data in TableView. In my dynamic TableView, I have buttons, so in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I declare it there.

I check and make sure that the retrieved data (so array) is not empty. However, the button's selector complains

> Expression resolves to an unused i-value

```
var users = [String]()

// First I store in users array and reload tableView

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell   

   cell.myBtn.tag = indexPath.row
   cell.myBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.btnClicked(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

   return cell
}

func btnClicked (sender:UIButton) {
    let btnRow = sender.tag
    if !self.users.isEmpty {
        self.users[btnRow]  // This line complains: Expression resolves to an unused i-value
    }   
}
```

Comment: So delete that line. It isn't doing anything, and that's what the warning message is telling you.

Comment: I need to access the value in the array

Comment: You are accessing it but not using it.

Comment: @matt Ye, that's the reason. Thanks alot

Comment: Actually, it's an unused l-value (that's l-value with a lower-case L as is Lima).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong syntax for `#selector`.

Use this:

```
cell.myBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.btnClicked(_:), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Edit:

```
self.users[btnRow]  // This line complains: Expression resolves to an unused i-value
```

This line is throwing the warning since you just access the value and never print or use it inside your app thus making it unused accessing of value and the warning.

Comment: `Expression resolves to an unused i-value` persists even though I change it to that. This isn't the reason of the problem

Comment: Oh alright! Thanks!